# Is there any way to check existence of a path in S3 bucket using AWS SDK for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to check whether there exist a path (e.g. /myTest) in my bucket or not. The only way that I can handle it is that try to find whether there exist an object in my bucket that its key matches the `path+'\/?.*'` regex.

AWS SDK for javascript has the function getObject that in its params gets an string for the `key` param. But it seems that the value of this parameter could not accept regex. So I'm not sure whether there is any way to check the existence of a path in S3 bucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `listObjects` with a `Prefix` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `listObjectsV2`

> **Important** 
>   This section describe the latest revision of the API. We recommend that you use this revised API, GET Bucket (List Objects) version 2, for application development. For backward compatibility, Amazon S3 continues to support the prior version of this API, GET Bucket (List Objects) version 1. For more information about the previous version, see GET Bucket (List Objects) Version 1.

Source: [amazon s3 api reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html)